# I am unable to assign a target of _blank in a Dojo LinkContainer

Tags: dojo

I'm using a Dojo `LinkContainer` within an `AccordionContainer`. My goal is to have the link open a PDF in a new window, but the target property in the link doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
<a href="ermHelp.pdf" target="_blank" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/LinkPane">
    Using the Environmental Resource Mapper
</a>
```

Any ideas as to how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/layout/LinkPane) it seems that the `LinkPane` works by replacing the content of the HTML element with the content in the link - in your case the PDF file.

Since your intention is to just open a file in a new window, you could just remove the `data-dojo-type` attribute and then it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Corina. I'll give that a shot.